# Remove element with array_diff_key() by one specific key

Tags: php

I want to remove one ore more array element using array_diff_key() with one specific key but the result is different

```
$a = [
        ['value' => 1, 'text' => '1 Hour'],
        ['value' => 12, 'text' => '12 Hour'],
        ['value' => 24, 'text' => '1 Day'],
    ];

$b = [
        ['value' => 12],    
    ];

$c = array_diff_key($a, $b);

//print_r($c);
//return Array ( [1] => Array ( [value] => 12 [text] => 12 Hour ) [2] => Array ( [value] => 24 [text] => 1 Day ))
```

Expected result

```
Array ( 
      [1] => Array ( 
        [value] => 1 
        [text] => 1 Hour ) 
      [2] => Array ( 
        [value] => 24 
        [text] => 1 Day ) 
)
```

I can get expected result if I set `text` in `$b` but in this case I don't want to set `text`.

Where i'm doing wrong? other solution is wellcome.

Thanks in advance

PS: `$b` can be one or more element

Comment: Based on what I understand, you simply want to remove the nested array in `$a`  where the value matches that of the incoming array `$b`, right?

Comment: `$b`  is an array or just you want to search `12` in `text` key ?

Comment: @terry, yes I want to remove $a element which match $b

Comment: @sahil, $b is array and I want to remove $a element which match $b

Answer (score 2):

Try below code,

> Check thorough loop.

```
<?php
    $a = [
            ['value' => 1, 'text' => '1 Hour'],
            ['value' => 12, 'text' => '12 Hour'],
            ['value' => 24, 'text' => '1 Day'],
        ];

    $b = [
            ['value' => 12]
        ];
    $c = array();


    function checkExists($array,$value){
        foreach($array as $k=>$values){
            if($values['value']==$value){
                return true;break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        if(checkExists($b,$v['value'])===false){
            $c[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [text] => 1 Hour
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 24
            [text] => 1 Day
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to author very complicated for loops. You can simply define your own comparator function when using `array_udiff()`:

```
$a = [
        ['value' => 1, 'text' => '1 Hour'],
        ['value' => 12, 'text' => '12 Hour'],
        ['value' => 24, 'text' => '1 Day'],
    ];

$b = [
        ['value' => 12],    
    ];

function comparator($a, $b)
{
    return $a['value'] - $b['value'];
}

$c = array_udiff($a, $b, 'comparator');
print_r($c);
```

That should give you the array you expected:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [value] => 1
        [text] => 1 Hour
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [value] => 24
        [text] => 1 Day
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't use `array_diff()`? You are misunderstanding `array_diff_keys()`; it only works with a single dimensional associative array—i.e., elements with keys. The first dimension of your array does not have any keys.

We can write a simple solution with `array_reduce()`:

```
$a = [
        ['value' => 1, 'text' => '1 Hour'],
        ['value' => 12, 'text' => '12 Hour'],
        ['value' => 24, 'text' => '1 Day'],
    ];

$b = [
        ['value' => 12]
    ];

function filter($v1,$v2)
{
  global $b;
  var_dump($v1,$v2);
  return ($b[0]['value'] == $v2['value'])
    ? $v1
    : array_merge($v1, [$v2]);
}

print_r(array_reduce($a,"filter",[]));
```

Short, sweet, and no explicit iterators nor temporary variables.